# Cursor becoming arrows on each side of a webpage?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have been attempting to create a webpage where the cursor changes, specifically pointing arrows at opposite directions, when it is on one side of the image to encourage the user to press next like a slideshow. Essentially the website example I saw has no arrows on the image slideshow but instead utilizes the cursor when the user moves it on either side of the image.

I have very basic html/css knowledge but I can't happen to find any references of what this might be using or what it is at all. I simply would just like to have this on my portfolio site, so any help is appreciated! I apologize if the question is a little confusing.

Comment: Create 2 divs positioned on the left/right with no content in them. Define them as whatever height and width, and add a hover state to change the cursor. Additionally, you can use your browsers developer tools to inspect the page you saw this on to see how they did it.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I have inspected these sites but genuinely just can't get a sense. The part that I am most confused on is how to connect this to an interactive image gallery. Would I create the 2 divs on top? I know about creating a split screen and using the cursor hover state but just don't understand how to use it as part of the image gallery. @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: You're going to need to include more details in your question if you want a more specific answer. The example website, for example. Or a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be even better.